# What plans were made for Buran post-flight processing?

Tags: reuse, buran

U.S. Space Shuttles underwent considerable [post-processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbiter_Processing_Facility#Processing_flow) after each flight.  Gases, liquids, and payloads were removed; engines were refurbished; thermal tiles were repaired; and everything was thoroughly inspected.  There were many buildings where these tasks were performed, including the [Orbiter Processing Facility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbiter_Processing_Facility) and the Main Engine Processing Facility.

[*Buran*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buran_(spacecraft)) was a similar reusable spacecraft built by the Soviet Union.  **What plans were there to prepare Buran for the next mission?**  For example, were there any buildings or procedures created (even if partially) to get ready for the next flight?

Related:

- [Were there problems with the Russian Buran space shuttle's reusability?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22299/26446) (describes the condition of *Buran* after flight)

Comment: We need someone who knows the abbreviations of the Baikonur Cosmodrome and decrypts this designation. - http://www.buran.ru/htm/team01.htm