# How was the Buran launch stack assembled?

Tags: launch-site, buran

There is plenty of information about how the U.S. Space Shuttle was assembled for launch.  **How was the Soviet Buran shuttle assembled?**

- Was it done at the pad, or in a separate building?
- In what order were the components placed?
- What is put together horizontally and then erected upright, or was it assembled vertically?
- What facilities/buildings/cranes/equipment were used in the process?

Related:

- [What plans were made for Buran post-flight processing?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/43350/26446)
- [Were there problems with the Russian Buran space shuttle's reusability?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22299/26446)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Buran" orbiters were assembled in Tushinskiy complex in Moscow (Тушинский авиастроительный завод). Than the orbiter articles were transported by [VM-T airplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myasishchev_VM-T). The iconic An-225 was not ready in 1988.

MIK-112 in Baikonur was used for preflight/postflight maintenance.

( From Russian wikipedia
[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Энергия_—_Буран](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F_%E2%80%94_%D0%91%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD))

Quote:

> Производство орбитальных кораблей осуществлялось на Тушинском машиностроительном заводе с 1980 года; к 1984 году был готов первый полномасштабный экземпляр. С завода корабли доставлялись водным транспортом (на барже под тентом) в город Жуковский, а оттуда (с аэродрома Жуковский) — воздушным транспортом (на специальном самолёте-транспортировщике ВМ-Т) — на аэродром «Юбилейный» космодрома Байконур.

Tranlation:

> The production of orbital ships has been carried out at the Tushino Machine-Building Plant since 1980; by 1984, the first full-blown instance was ready. From the factory, ships were delivered by water (on a barge under cover) to the city of Zhukovsky near Moscow, and from there (from the [Zhukovsky airfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhukovsky_International_Airport)) - by air (on a special BM-T carrier aircraft) to the Yubileiny aerodrome of the Baikonur Cosmodrome.

Here are couple of images of Buran assembly:

[image]

[source](https://stimul.online/articles/science-and-technology/buran-triumf-i-tragediya/)

[image]

[source](http://www.npomolniya.ru/istoriya-predpriyatiya.html)

---

Energia rocket was too big, the parts were transported by air or by train and assembled in Baikonur.

Some details about Buran can be found also on site **[buran.ru](http://buran.ru/htm/homepage.htm)** (it has [**English version**](http://buran.ru/htm/molniya.htm) but it's some less detailed). I don't know how readable will be plain google translate of the Russian version...

---

[Here](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fhabrastorage.org%2Fwebt%2F1-%2Fii%2Flw%2F1-iilw8nzfzil5hsgm4-9xrmoii.jpeg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fhabr.com%2Fru%2Fpost%2F412271%2F&tbnid=ygCy2wXXFaxpoM&vet=12ahUKEwign6bIsI7qAhXBvyoKHVqrCFIQMygregUIARCEAg..i&docid=H3wRMOIvTM-hrM&w=1024&h=768&q=%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD&ved=2ahUKEwign6bIsI7qAhXBvyoKHVqrCFIQMygregUIARCEAg) is collection of photos of Buran and Energia rocket, including in-hangar photos, but not so high-resolution and with Russian captions.

---

[Here](https://fishki.net/2008047-redkij-transportnyj-samolyot-vm-t-atlant.html?sign=676805851965863%2C125833367610677) is plogpost about ВТ-М cargo plane. (In Russian, but with many nice photos, including transporting Buran and Energia's conponents.) Photo from there:

[image]

Here a picture of loading of Buran on An-225:

[image]

---

[Here](https://www.sciencephoto.com/media/148312/view/buran-space-shuttle-before-flight) are some photos of Buran installation to Energia rocket. You can see all operations were horizontal.

[image]

---

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJMjEbtjUoM) is video inside MIK-112 in Baikonur (in year 2017).

---

P.S.

After second try I've found the real [Klondike of Buran-Energia photos here](http://www.darkroastedblend.com/2007/11/rare-photos-of-russian-buran-space.html)!

The first photo there shows the crane parts for mating Buran to Energia:

[image]

---

I also found photo of Energia assembly with side boosters.

[image]

[source](http://www.astronaut.ru/bookcase/books/stromsky/text/10.htm)

Answer (score 17):

It was done horizontally, in a separate building called MIK-112 (MIK is translated as ‘assembly and testing building’)

See more details and photos here:
http://www.russianspaceweb.com/baikonur_energia_112.html

Comment: "монтажно-испытательный корпус на 112-й площадке"

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VOpyCA-aQsA) has some footage of Buran being prepared, rolled out, and (briefly) erected.